# jquery closest find for image inside the particular div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I used the following HTML in my page

```
<div class="edge-img-sec">
    <img src="img1" alt="edge-icon" class="edge-icon1">
    <img src="img2" alt="right-icon" class="edge-icon1-right">
</div>

<div class="edge-img-sec">
    <img src="img3" alt="edge-icon" class="edge-icon1">
    <img src="img4" alt="right-icon" class="edge-icon1-right">
</div>
```

Jquery script:-

```
$( ".edge-img-sec" ).click(function(){
    alert('aa');
    $(this).closest('img').find('.edge-icon1-right').hide();
});
```

By clicking the `edge-img-sec` div i want to hide the corresponding `edge-icon1-right` image.

I used the above code. But it is not working. What I am doing wrong here. please help me.

Comment: where this exist `edge-img-sec` in your html? i didn't see any element with this class

Comment: where is edge-img-sec class in your html code..

Comment: also... why bother with `closest('img')` when you are specifying `find('edge-icon1-right')`?

Comment: @aequalsb maybe because there are multiple elements with the same class?

Comment: but that's what `find()` is for -- ie: find->selector inside this->clcked-element

Comment: `closest` is for searching **up** the tree. `find` is for searching down

Comment: Ah, yes...missed that. Quite right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like below (using `children()`):-

```js
$( ".edge-img-sec" ).click(function(){
    $(this).children('.edge-icon1-right').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edge-img-sec">
    <img src="img1" alt="edge-icon" class="edge-icon1"><br>
    <img src="img2" alt="right-icon" class="edge-icon1-right"><br>
</div>
<br>
<div class="edge-img-sec">
    <img src="img3" alt="edge-icon" class="edge-icon1"><br>
    <img src="img4" alt="right-icon" class="edge-icon1-right"><br>
</div>
```

Or using `find()`:-

```js
$( ".edge-img-sec" ).click(function(){
    $(this).find('.edge-icon1-right').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edge-img-sec">
    <img src="img1" alt="edge-icon" class="edge-icon1"><br>
    <img src="img2" alt="right-icon" class="edge-icon1-right"><br>
</div>
<br>
<div class="edge-img-sec">
    <img src="img3" alt="edge-icon" class="edge-icon1"><br>
    <img src="img4" alt="right-icon" class="edge-icon1-right"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: i think the OP's logic using `find()` was fine -- `children()` works but it's nature refers only to direct descendants. if the OP needed to change the HTML structure and put a wrapper around `.edge-icon1-right` the jQuery code would break -- but not when using `find()`

Comment: @aequalsb  based on his current structure i gave the answer. But i have added both.Thanks

Comment: that's better :) but the OP did refer to `find()` in his original question maybe `children()` should be offered as the alternative... oh... and `children()` would have slightly less overhead as it would likely traverse less elements in many situations

Comment: i think the OP should accept this answer -- it is thorough and offers 2 methods

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  $( ".edge-img-sec" ).click(function(){
        $(this).find('img.edge-icon1-right').hide();
  });
```

Comment: this is the way to do it unless you specifically want to use `children()` for traversing direct descendants only. another caveat... using `find('img.*')` adds a little bit of overhead